# How did Zeref "Black Wizard" get cursed?

Tags: fairy-tail-zero

How did Zeref get cursed? Some people think it was Mard Geer. I'm so sorry to trample on that thesis, but Zeref created Mard Geer and it is said that E.N.D, I mean Natsu, is the strongest demon who so happens to be Zeref's brother.

I was thinking that maybe Natsu cursed Zeref, but Natsu was out searching the world for his foster parent Igneel, right? Then I thought maybe Mavis cursed him? Not true either, because in the little flashback, Zeref already had the Death curse when he met Mavis and Mavis is way too sweet! Yeah some of you may be thinking "Mavis is the Fairy Tatican and she has won many wars" but I'm a Zervis shipper, sorry!

Then that had me thinking: does anybody remember that crucial detail (it happened fast but not fast enough) that Zeref 'lived' with all the monks, so maybe they cursed him? So then I did my research and some monks are, umm I don't wanna type evil, umm BAD. Most of the monks back then worshipped god. I watched a lot of religous anime! So that was soon to be proven wrong.

Yep, I can't answer my own question. I wonder if Hiro Mashima wanted us to think this?

Comment: Related: [Who cursed poor Zeref?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/23091)

Answer (score 3):

Zeref experimented on forbidden magic which gave him the [Contradictory Curse](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Ankhseram_Black_Magic). So the more he values life, the more uncontrollable his power becomes. And when he doesn't value life, the less destructive he gets.

The same curse happened with Mavis who also used the forbidden magic. So basically anyone who experiments or conducts black magic is automatically cursed with the Contradictory Curse.

Comment: Arigato Mr! Why didn't I think of that dang it but Arigato x 10!

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Thomas said, Zeref was researching and experimenting with forbidden magic in order to resurrect Natsu. It was this research that angered Ankhseram, the god that (as far as I am aware) the monks were worshiping. It was Ankhseram who is said to have cursed Zeref with the curse of contradictions, which is also known as Ankhseram Black Magic. This is stated in chapter 436 of the manga.